# Calling file on branched path in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following file structure

```
example.com/
example.com/folder-A/childfolder-B/page1.php
example.com/folder-A/childfolder-C/page2.php
```

How do I echo `page2.php` from `page1.php`? I figured that I could go back with `'../'` but I do not know how to branch out on a different tree/node.

Comment: `include '../childfolder-C/page2.php'` ?

Answer (score 0):

Always use absolute paths.

```
readfile(dirname(__DIR__) . "/childfolder-C/page2.php");
```